# How to run "for loop" in a list of hosts from a hop server using for or any loop?

Tags: bash

Want to run "for loop" from a hop server to a list of servers. If I run the for loop in individual server, it works fine but I don't know how to nest it and make it work from a hop server.

For loop output from individual host:

```
$ for i in {a..b}; do echo Volume: /dev/sd$i; sudo /usr/sbin/smartctl -a /dev/sd$i | egrep -i "model|serial"; done
Volume: /dev/sda
Device Model:     TOSHIBA THNSNJ256GCSU
Serial Number:    35FS109IT88W
Volume: /dev/sdb
Model Family:     Seagate Constellation ES.3
Device Model:     ST4000NM0033-9ZM170
Serial Number:    Z1Z7EK85
$
```

Below is how I usually run "for loop" from a hop server:

```
$ for i in `cat hostlist`;do echo $i;ssh $i "uptime";echo " ";done
```

Please suggest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r host
do {
  printf "%s\n" "$host"
  ssh -t -- "$host" '
    for i in a b
    do
      printf "%s\n" "Volume: /dev/sd$i"
      sudo smartctl -a "/dev/sd$i" | grep -Ei "model|serial"
    done'
  } 0<&3
done 3<&0 <hostlist
```

I am assuming hosts are listed in the `hostlist` file, one per line. `IFS=` and `-r` are probably unnecessary here, because host names are unlikely to contain blank characters or backslashes; they should not hurt, though. Similarly, reading your `hostlist` in a `for` loop is probably fine in this case, but using `while` loops for that is a good habit. See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/315749) for more on this.

For each host, `ssh` is invoked with the `-t` option to force the allocation of a pseudo-terminal on the remote host, needed to type in the password that `sudo` will ask you (unless you configured it not to).

A new file descriptor is opened (`3<&0`), duplicating that of the outer standard input, to make the latter available to the body of the loop (which is wrapped in `{` `}` for this reason). `ssh` would otherwise read from `hostlist` and be unable to interact with you (for instance, when `sudo` requires your password).

I replaced `echo` with `printf` because the latter is [more robust](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/315749) (even if, again, it was not strictly necessary here). And I replaced `egrep` with `grep -E` because (looking at the GNU manual) the former is deprecated and only provided for backward compatibility.

Finally, I replaced the brace expansion (`{a..b}`) with `a b` to make the script able to run in any POSIX shell, including those that do not support that feature (e.g. `dash`).

Comment: Wow! Worked like a charm. Thank you so much! :)